# Let $R$ be binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ defined by $xRy$ iff $x\leq y\leq 2x$ . Is $R$ reflexive? Is $R$ (anti)symmetric? Is $R$ transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Hi I'm not sure about this question, can anybody help me out?

Let $R$ be binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$ defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x\leq y\leq 2x$. Is $R$ reflexive? Is $R$ symmetric? Is $R$ antisymmetric? Is $R$ transitive?

Thank you.

Comment: Start by writing the definition of each property. Then translate it replacing each $xRy$ with its definition. Then ask yourself if and how this can be true.

Comment: Precision: when true you can show the inequalities, if not just exhibit a numerical counter-example.